# I have some problems when making two siblings communicate with each other through event bus

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to click a button in `Servers`, and `currentStatus` in `ServerDetails` will be changed to `status` property in `server` array, but my `currentStatus` in `ServerDetails` is still "Server Details are currently not updated"
Please help

main.js

```
export const eventBus = new Vue({
  methods: {
    changeStatus(stat) {
      this.$emit("statChanges", stat);
    }
  }
});
```

Servers.vue

```
 <li class="list-group-item" v-for="elem in server" :key="elem.id">
      <button @click="updateStatus(elem.status)">Server #{‌{elem.id}}</button>
      <p>{‌{serverstatus}}</p>
 </li>

<script>
import { eventBus } from "../../main";

export default {
  props: ["serverstatus"],
  data: function() {
    return {
      server: [
        { id: 1, status: "Level 1" },
        { id: 2, status: "Level 2" },
        { id: 3, status: "Level 3" },
        { id: 4, status: "Level 4" },
        { id: 5, status: "Level 5" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateStatus(x) {
      this.serverstatus = x;
      eventBus.changeStatus(this.serverstatus);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

ServerDetails.vue

```
<p>{‌{currentStatus}}</p>

<script>
import { eventBus } from "../../main";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentStatus: "Server Details are currently not updated"
    };
  },
  create() {
    eventBus.$on("statChanges", stat => {
      this.currentStatus = stat;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Try `created()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lifecycle hook `create` in Vue. You should use `created` instead.